# angular 2 flex layout: Can't bind to ngStyle.md since it isn't a known property of div

Tags: angular, material-design

Iam using flex layout with angular 2.3.1, I am trying to create a responsive style using the responsive api's provided by flex layout module, my divs looks like this

```
<div class="container popular-projects" classfxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap="wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="center"
     fxLayoutGap="30px"
     fxLayoutGap.xs="5px">
<div class="item" [ngStyle]="{width:'263px',height:'384px'}" [ngStyle.md]="{width:'156px',height:'257px'}" >

<div [ngStyle]="{'padding-left':'11px','font-size':'18px', 'padding-top': '10px'}" [ngStyle.md]="{'padding-left':'10px','font-size':'14px', 'padding-top': '12px'}" class="title">     PROJECT NAME</div>
<div [ngStyle]="{'padding-left':'11px','font-size':'16px', 'padding-top': '10px'}" [ngStyle.md]="{'padding-left':'10px','font-size':'11px', 'padding-top': '10px'}" class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce imperdiet ac arcu in auctor.</div>
</div>
```

the flex layout directives are working normally until I started using the binding [ngStyle.md].

in my app.module I imported flexlayoutModule like this

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";
```

then I added it to the imports so its accessed in all the application

```
   imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
MaterialModule,
FlexLayoutModule,
Md2Module,
MdGridListModule,
routing,
CommonModule
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

import `FlexLayoutModule` in the module where your component is declared

Comment: import the module in the component is equivalent to importing in the app.module, when importing in app.module basically you are importing in all project

Comment: no, if you want to use a component declared in Module A inside a component declared in module B, you have to import A in be B even if A is declared in `AppModule`. that's why we import `CommonModule` in each module we use `ngIf` and `ngFor` in.

Comment: please correct me if im wrong , normally angular2 applications are bootstraped from AppModule so importing any module in appModule is the same as importing it in every component, not sure about creating more than module, never tried it.

Comment: first we don't import a module in a component. for large scale app you have to create mutiple modules

Comment: we don't import a module in a component? are you sure about this , because I myself imported some modules in components

Comment: there is no `imports` array  in `@component`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138661/discussion-between-amer-qarabsa-and-bougarfaoui-el-houcine).

Answer (score 0):

see here https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/215

Looks like they are fixing it / fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
npm i -s @angular/flex-layout @angular/cdk
```

And then

```
    import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
...

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [ FlexLayoutModule ],
    ...
});
```